Question about twin studies
Back on July 18, I have asked the question: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/29741/how-can-a-researcher-take-into-consideration-the-ethical-concerns-related-to-twi.
The question has started with two upvotes, but after setting the bounty to the question, one of the mods has said to be more specific. I have made an edit after that. Then one of the users has asked me to add what ethical concerns I think apply here. Then I make more edits to the question. I have made several edits to the current version of the question. But the bounty has failed without any answer. So, I have deleted the question for now to deal with it later.
Today, I have come back to undelete the question after the feedback I receive here. Is the current version of the question worthy of an answer? If so, I will just wait for an answer. If not, what other improvement is required? Then, I will make the required improvements.

I believe you have already received sufficient feedback on the question itself.
But, one thing which still strikes me as odd is the way you incorporated that feedback into subsequent question edits.
In your last edit you decided to be agnostic about established ethical guidelines. In previous edits you in fact linked to specific guidelines. A couple of comments have pointed out you have in essence answered the question yourself by including those guidelines.
Would an answer re-introducing those guidelines answer your question? If not, the question is still unclear. If yes, your edits strike me as ill-intended.
I can't speak for others, but on my part, hence, the down votes.

"In your last edit you decided to be agnostic about established ethical guidelines. In previous edits you in fact linked to specific guidelines. A couple of comments have pointed out you have in essence answered the question yourself by including those guidelines."
https://psychology.stackexchange.com/posts/29741/revisions
So, now there are 32 revisions in the question. Which revision has those guidelines?

Apparently, the first.

I have decided that I must ask a question on a featured site and have embarked on a crusade to try to get a psychology-related question. Can the current version of the question be answered?

@ArunabhBhattacharya The help says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" - if you do not have an actual problem in Psychology and Neuroscience and are instead on a crusade to have a question answered because a site was "featured", it does not seem like you should post.
